# Using "flag"-technique of jira with custom field as SIL Power Action

Tags: jira, feedback

I already searched the whole web for this function, but couldn't find it yet. I know there is a "error"-management on poweractions in jira for custom-fields, to show the user, that some entered fields are not correct - and that works like a charm. But is there really no way to show the user for example for an successful action just a short feedback-message on the upper right in jira (such as "New Ticket JIRA-123 had been generated" or similar)? Sometimes jira itself presents some info-messages there as well, thus the functionality should be there.

I mean, it is even possible via javascript to trigger those messages. see also the flag-documentation as follows:
https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/flag.html

Via console I could verify those actions and trigger even those example messages in our jira-environment.

Since I couldn't find a SIL-function to trigger those messages I tried to execute those javascript as an alternative. But I couldn't find a way for this either.

So what am I missing here? Thanks for your help in advance ...

We are using following JIRA-version:
Atlassian JIRA Project Management Software (v8.20.11#820011-sha1:0629dd8)

together with the Power Actions from anovapps; created as described as follows: https://anovaapps.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KBA/pages/1776085/Configuring+a+Power+Actions+custom+field